# Any suggestions on why the C++(community) plugin doesn't generate LOCs with the sonar-runner?

Tags: c++, plugins, sonar-runner

When I run sonar-runner on a C++ project, it does not generate Lines of code count.

I'm using the Sonar C++ Community Plugin
  http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=185073817

I'm not running any preprocessing prior to running the sonar-runner.

Do I need to run any preprocessing on the C++ code prior to run the sonar-runner?

I'm using:

Sonar: 3.5
Sonar-runner: 2.0
C++ Plugin: sonar-cxx-plugin-0.2.jar

sonar-project.properties:

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=external:CS
sonar.projectName=CS3D
sonar.projectVersion=2.0.0
# optional description
sonar.projectDescription=Crystal Space 3D.

# path to source directories (required)
sonar.sources=plugins,libs,apps,mk
# path to test source directories (optional)
sonar.tests=engine/test
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you tell it otherwise Sonar goes ahead and assumes the project is a java project. For other languages you need to let it know...

So a starting point would be to add the following line:

`sonar.language=c++`

It should report the a lines of code count without any preprocessing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, PeterSW. Please consider adding an explanation to your answer to make it a more useful resource to visitors looking for help with this type of problem.